# Python SKLearn: How to Get Feature Names After OneHotEncoder?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to get the feature names of a data set after it has been transformed by SKLearn OneHotEncoder.

In [active_features_ attribute in OneHotEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33596950) one can see a very good explanation how the attributes `n_values_`, `feature_indices_` and `active_features_` get filled after `transform()` was executed.

My question is:

For e.g. DataFrame based input data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1, 2,0], "b": [0,1,4, 5], "c":[0,1,4, 5]}).as_matrix()
```

How does the code look like to get from the original feature names `a`, `b` and `c` to a list of the transformed feature names 
(like e.g:

`a-0`,`a-1`, `a-2`, `b-0`, `b-1`, `b-2`, `b-3`, `c-0`, `c-1`, `c-2`, `c-3`

or

`a-0`,`a-1`, `a-2`, `b-0`, `b-1`, `b-2`, `b-3`, `b-4`, `b-5`, `b-6`, `b-7`, `b-8`

or anything that helps to see the assignment of encoded columns to the original columns).

Background: I would like to see the feature importances of some of the algorithms to get a feeling for which feature have the most effect on the algorithm used.

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to know.  You want to know the code to "get from  ... to ...".  Do you merely want to list the names of the new columns?  See the code the encoder uses to generate new column names?  "See the assignment" confuses the issue,as those columns are *not* "assigned to" the original columns; they are derived from the original columns, and no longer have a data-flow connection..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pd.get_dummies()`:

```
pd.get_dummies(data["a"],prefix="a")
```

will give you:

```
    a_0 a_1 a_2
0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0
2   0   0   1
3   1   0   0
```

which can automatically generates the column names. You can apply this to all your columns and then get the columns names. No need to convert them to a numpy matrix.

So with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1, 2,0], "b": [0,1,4, 5], "c":[0,1,4, 5]})
data = df.as_matrix()
```

the solution looks like:

```
columns = df.columns
my_result = pd.DataFrame()
temp = pd.DataFrame()
for runner in columns:
    temp = pd.get_dummies(df[runner], prefix=runner)
    my_result[temp.columns] = temp
print(my_result.columns)

>>Index(['a_0', 'a_1', 'a_2', 'b_0', 'b_1', 'b_4', 'b_5', 'c_0', 'c_1', 'c_4',
       'c_5'],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you can use `feature_indices_` to identify which columns correspond to which feature.

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
data = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1, 2,0], "b": [0,1,4, 5], "c":[0,1,4, 5]}).as_matrix()
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
ohe_fitted = ohe.fit_transform(data)
print(ohe_fitted)
print(ohe.feature_indices_) # [ 0  3  9 15]
```

From the above `feature_indices_` we know if we spliced the OneHotEncoded data from `0:3` we would get the features corresponding to the first column in `data` like so:

```
print(ohe_fitted[:,0:3])
```

Each column in the spliced data represents a value in the first feature. The first column is 0, the second 1 and the third column is 2. To illustrate this on the spliced data, the column labels would look like:

```
  a_0 a_1 a_2
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

Note that features are sorted first before they are encoded.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the open source package feature-engine:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from feature_engine.encoding import OneHotEncoder

# load titanic data from openML
pd.read_csv('https://www.openml.org/data/get_csv/16826755/phpMYEkMl')

# divide into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data[['sex', 'embarked']],  # predictors for this example
    data['survived'],  # target
    test_size=0.3,  # percentage of obs in test set
    random_state=0)  # seed to ensure reproducibility

ohe_enc = OneHotEncoder(
    top_categories=None,
    variables=['sex', 'embarked'],
    drop_last=True)

ohe_enc.fit(X_train)

X_train = ohe_enc.transform(X_train)
X_test = ohe_enc.transform(X_test)

X_train.head()
```

You should see this output returned:

```
   sex_female  embarked_S  embarked_C  embarked_Q
501            1           1           0           0
588            1           1           0           0
402            1           0           1           0
1193           0           0           0           1
686            1           0           0           1
```

More details about feature engine here:

https://www.trainindata.com/feature-engine

https://github.com/feature-engine/feature_engine

https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: your tmp variable wasn't declared!

Answer (score 0):

There is a OneHotEncoder that does all the work for you.

Package sksurv has a OneHotEncoder that will return a pandas Dataframe with all the column names set-up for you.  Check it out.  Make sure you set-up an environment to play with the encoder to ensure it doesn't break your current environment.  This encoder saved me a lot of time and effort.

[scikit-suvival GitHub](https://github.com/sebp/scikit-survival)

[OneHotEncoder Documentation](https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/sksurv.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sksurv.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)

Answer (score 0):

`OneHotEncoder` now has a method `get_feature_names`.  You can use `input_features=data.columns` to match to the training data.